# How to know an application is available?

Tags: cloudify

when I use the cloudify(2.7) to deploy an application(e.g. an application app includes two services A and B ),I try to use the `Admin.addEventListener()` to add some eventListener,but it does't work !

I try to add the `ProcessingUnitStatusChangedEventListener` ,when I debug the code,the value of `(ProcessingUnitStatusChangedEvent)event.getNewStatus()` changes from `SCHEDULED` to `INTACT`,then `SCHEDULED`,then `INTACT` again,
I also try to add the `ProcessingUnitInstanceLifecycleEventListener`,when I debug the code,the status is `intact`,but the service is not available!

Is there any other listener or method to know the application(not the services) is available,or I use the `listener` in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the Admin API is internal - use it at your own risk. And you should not be using it the way you are - Cloudify adds a lot of logic on top of the internal Admin API.

Second, it is not exactly clear where you are executing your code from.

You can always use the rest client to get an accurate state of the application. Look at https://github.com/CloudifySource/cloudify/blob/master/rest-client/src/main/java/org/cloudifysource/restclient/RestClient.java#L388

In addition, if you are running this code in a service lifecycle event handler, the easiest way to implement this is to have your 'top' level service, the one that should be available last, write an application entry to the shared attributes store in its 'postStart' event. Everyone else can just periodically poll on this entry. The polling itself is very fast, all in-memory operations.

If you do not have a top-level service, or your logic is more complicated then that, you would need to use the Service Context API to scan each service and its instances to see if they are up. An explanation on getting service instance state is available here:
[cloudify service dependsOn other service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924933/cloudify-service-dependson-other-service/26084630#26084630)